# JQueryValidation prevents form from submitting, even when valid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that is validated by the excellent JQueryValidation plugin.

However, for some reason, the form does not want to submit at all when validated. I've isolated the problem and it's due to the validation itself - my form HTML is valid and submits fine without the JQueryValidation.

Here are the objects I am passing to the JqueryValidation object:

```
var validator = $("#registrationForm").validate({

        debug: true,

        rules: {

            registerName: {
                required: true
            },

            registerEmail: {
                required: true,
                email:true,
                remote: "http://beta.build2trade.com/Testmail.asp",
            },

            registerPassword: {
                required: true
            },

            registerPasswordConfirm: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#registerPassword"
            },

            registerSub: {
                pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$",
                remote: "http://beta.build2trade.com/testsub.asp",
                required: { 
                    depends: function(element) {
                        if ($("#domain-type-3").is(":checked")){
                            console.log("Subdomain Radiobutton checked");
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            console.log("Subdomain Radiobutton not checked");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },



        },

        messages : {

            registerName: "Please type in your name.",
            registerEmail: "Please enter a valid email.",
            registerPassword: "Please type in your password.",
            registerPasswordConfirm: "Please confirm your password.",
            registerSub: "Invalid Subdomain."

        },

    });
```

This is how the form behaves:

All the fields validate perfectly and as expected, showing the correct messages at the correct times. But when you click the Submit button (which is a  element with a type of "submit"), nothing happens. The button is dead.

The pattern.js file is included just below the code above, and the subdomain field validates correctly by RegEx.

I had a sneaking suspicion that it might be due to the "depends" function on the registerSub element, but commenting those lines out has no effect.

Any insight would be appreciated... thank you!

Comment: `$("#registrationForm").valid()` returns `true`

Comment: You need to read up on cross-site scripting and how it relates to JavaScript.   In other words you just can't put a full URL in the remote method if that domain is not the same location as your JavaScript.

Comment: I understand that - the remote method offers a way to query remote scripts to do server-side validation.

I logged this issue with the plugin developer who has acknowledged it.

Comment: Yes, [and as the developer stated too](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1045), only as long _as they're on the same domain_.  I see how you're claiming `.valid()` should be `false` if the `remote` method cannot connect.  However, I also see [the developer's point about how to handle a remote request that's not properly functioning](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1044#issuecomment-38351937), as in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `debug: true,` which will prevent the form submit even when it is valid... it is just for testing....

remove it and it should be fine

Comment: ... that was quick. Thanks Arun!

Unfortunately, the problem still persists after removing debug:true. I do have other forms with this line set that post correctly, too.

Comment: @Gandalf, you are mistaken if you think you can submit a form while `debug: true` is in place.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved!

The issue lay in the fact that I was using a localhost environment and had a `remote` validation rule.

I was working in a localhost environment and using a `remote` rule to validate a domain name and an email address field. On the local environment, these validations failed due to HTTP security restrictions.

However, the problem I was having was that the form wasn't posting, at all.

At first I thought this might be because the form wasn't valid, but I used `console.log` to check the valid() method, and it returned `true`.

As such, I thought that there must have been some kind of event blocking going on that prevented the form from submitting.

But, when I published my code to a live environment to check it, the issue disappeared.

So, it seems that the "remote" method validates the form, but if there is an element that is validated remotely, that validation won't be counted in the valid() method.

I've logged this with JQueryValidation. Thanks to everyone for reading.